# Why $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2 :\, y=x\sin \frac1x\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$ is connected but not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I wonder why the set of all points in the plane satisfying $y = x\sin \frac {1}{
x}$ together with the origin is connected but not compact.

Is there any example of a open cover that is not finite?

Comment: The image of this set by the first projection is $\mathbb{R}$ which is not compact.

Comment: What you need is not an infinite cover. You need an infinite cover from which you cannot extract a finite subcover.

Comment: As for connectedness, observe that the parts of your set with $x>0$ and $x<0$ are obviously path-connected, hence connected. Their closures are also connected and they happen to have the origin as their common point. Therefore, their union is connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set is connected because this is the graph of a continuous function. Namely, $g(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g(0)=0$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

That set is an unbounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$, and therefore it is not compact.